# NameError: global name 'MyClass' is not defined in Pepper/Nao

Tags: python-2.7, class, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

Update: to work around the combination of *Choregraphe* and Python, I rejected the idea of having `@classmethod`. Instead I raise AlMemory events in `MyCustomClass` when I want to make use of `MyClass`.

I read many posts on NameError but still couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I write a program with *Choregraphe* using the Python box for Nao.

I got the followings:

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass): #GeneratedClass is given

 def __init__(self):
    GeneratedClass.__init__(self)

 @classmethod
 def doSomething(cls, a):
    print a

class myCustomClass():
 def func(self):
    MyClass.doSomething(a)
```

When calling `func()` from myCustomClass, I got `NameError` on *MyClass*.

> [ERROR] behavior.box :FMBox::createPythonModule:0 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_1275012824__root__test_1: User class evaluation failed with the error:
>   
>   global name 'MyClass' is not defined

How can I fix that?

Comment: You should update your code to the standard 4 spaces indentation.

Comment: Where is `doSomething` method definition?

Comment: Also `do` is keyword in Python, use some other name for this method.

Comment: @Hitobat no it isn't.

Comment: Latest states: I changed `self` to `cls` according to @Rarblack 's feedback. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Where is your User class?

Comment: I updated my code even simpler version which is almost your code above. Mine is working fine but as I assume from the error you get, the cause of the issue is in User class but still your code need changes I made in mine.

Answer (score 0):

As a start your `@method` and *class structure* is **wrong**.

When I ran your code it says this :

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):

 @classmethod
 def do(self, a):
     return a

class myCustomClass():
 def func(self):
    MyClass.do(a)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 236, in <module>
    class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
NameError: name 'GeneratedClass' is not defined
```

Your class structure is completely wrong. If you want to pass a parameter, use `__init__` method.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, GeneratedClass):
        self.generated_class = GeneratedClass

     def do(self):
         doSomething(self.generated_class)

class MyCustomClass:
    def func(self):
        GeneratedClass = 1
        MyClass(GeneratedClass).do()

myCustomClass().func()
```

If you are using `@methodclass` you should not pass `self`, it is `cls`. Like in this example:

```
from datetime import date

# random Person
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def fromBirthYear(cls, name, birthYear):
        return cls(name, date.today().year - birthYear)

    def display(self):
        print(self.name + "'s age is: " + str(self.age))

person = Person('Adam', 19)
person.display()

person1 = Person.fromBirthYear('John',  1985)
person1.display()
```

In case if you are trying inheritance take this is an example how it should be.

```
class Mapping:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.items_list = []
        self.__update(iterable)

    def update(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            self.items_list.append(item)

    __update = update   # private copy of original update() method

class MappingSubclass(Mapping):

    def update(self, keys, values):
        # provides new signature for update()
        # but does not break __init__()
        for item in zip(keys, values):
            self.items_list.append(item)
```

Now **all** in one according to yours:

```
class GeneratedClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myclass = self

    def print(self):
        print('hello_people')

class MyClass(GeneratedClass):

    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)
        print(a)

    @classmethod
    def give_param(cls, a):
        return cls(a)

class myCustomClass:
    def func(self):
        MyClass.give_param('aa')

myCustomClass().func()
```

**NOTE:** I have used *python 3.x*.

Comment: First of all, the class `GeneratedClass` exists. I have no access to the code of this class. `MyClass` is initialized with `def __init__(self):       GeneratedClass.__init__(self)`. But even I changed `self` to `cls`. It doesn't work for me. Your example neither :( I'm not sure if it is kinda specialities of Choregraphe.

Comment: @catie if you are trying to use classmethod you cannot pass self, it is cls first of all and second the reason why your code is not working is you are trying to use classmethod but not returning any class. MyClass.dosomething(a) is how  classmethod is called. As I have mentioned in my answer classmethod should return cls() since your init takes no argument.

Comment: As, an addition if you carefully read my answer you will see a direct solution to your question. I cannot myself run your code to check it because of lacking libraries and etc.

Comment: A simple solution is deleting classmethod annotation and directy assigning parameters. In this case calling will be this: MyClass().dosomething(a)

Comment: @Rarblck Thanks for following up. Especially thank you for explaining the classmethod concept. This is helpful for me. Following your advice, I corrected my codes. However, the problem persists. I couldn't even instantiate MyClass().

Answer (score 0):

I think "MyClass" is replaced on the fly by the Choregraphe/PythonBridge interpreter invoked when you press run.

As you can see each choregraphe box classes are named "MyClass", they are so replaced and changed by a generated name like root/class/boxname...

You could try calling and printing the self.getName() in MyClass, to have a clue.

So in your case, you could:

1. add doSomething directly in myClass
2. create a not postprocessed, eg:

as:

```
class MyVeryOneClass:
 def __init__(self):
    ...
```